# How do I create and write a file with for loop?

Tags: python

So I have a text file that has writing in it and I created a for loop which finds a specified string in the file and prints out the lines that have the string contained in it. But now I'm stuck because I want to modify the code so I can write a new file that contains what it already printed out.

I've tried researching around for answers, but I can't seem to find any solutions or how to even search for what I am trying to do. I tried carefully looking at the parameters of print function and join method.

```
file = open("datalist.txt", "r")
s = "hello"
file_export = open("newfile.txt", "w")

for lines in file:
    lines = lines.lower()
    index = lines.find(s)
    if index != -1:
        indexed = lines[index:]
        print(lines[index:], end='')
```

The printed message I need is something along the lines of:

```
hello,
hello:
hello;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print` is not the function you are looking for, to write into a file you need to use `file.write` (or `file.writeline`), take a look to the [input and output documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

To give an idea, your code should be something like this:

```py
file = open("datalist.txt", "r")
s = "hello"
file_export = open("newfile.txt", "w")

for lines in file:
    lines = lines.lower()
    index = lines.find(s)
    if index != -1:
        indexed = lines[index:]
        print(lines[index:], end='')
        file_export.write(lines[index:])
```

Also, note that you should close your file when you are done, so add the following at the end:

```py
file.close()
file_export.close()
```

Or, as an alternative, use the [context manager](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html) that automatically closes your file.